# How does my router identify different devices?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I was looking into a device list of all the devices connected to my router and I was curious about how the router keeps them all straight. The names of each device was listed next to the DHCP assigned IP and everything and I was simply wondering how it knows what device is which when the IPs are consistently changing.

My router is a new frontier one but I'm not sure exactly which model since my sister gave it to me.

Comment: Your router will use the device MAC address - a unique hardware address given to a network adapter. The device name you see is called a hostname but not all devices report these. The router has a number of tables that it keeps up to date with what device has what IP - in a nutshell.

Answer (score 2):

It knows the 'names' (which are actually the computer/device's self declared DNS 'host' names) because it got them when the devices grabbed DHCP from the router. Look at field 12 below.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#DHCP_information

Windows and other OS get this from the 'computer name' or 'host name' or whatever they call it to make it sound friendly.

If your home router support DDNS (Dynamic DNS) then it may also be allowing you to resolve via DNS by those listed names.

99% of home routers run Linux (but custom, embedded versions). Your router is doing something similar to this, but maybe with a lighter weight version of bind.

As the other posters noted, the MAC address is the unique identifier. But the MAC alone would not tell the router anything about the name.

https://wiki.debian.org/DDNS

Answer (score 1):

Routers identify devices by their physical address, known as the [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) (media access control address), which is unique.

Based on the MAC address, the DHCP service assigns each device to an IP address, based on the list of free and taken IP addresses range it has.

If a device had already an IP address assigned to it, and the lease time didn't expire, the router will give the device the same IP address as before, otherwise it will give it a free address from the IP addresses range. Depending on the router features, it could give it the same IP address as before if it's not taken by another device, or it could give it the same address over and over again if it is manually reserved for that MAC address (some routers have these options).

As for the names you see, again it depends on the router: some routers will only show you the MAC addresses and you manually have to assign them a name, while others interogate the device on certain network protocols to find their names.