# Flush DNS cache on Netgear r6220 router

Tags: networking, router, dns

I have a PC that used to have windows on it. After having it sit powered off for some months, I've resurrected it with an Ubuntu 22.04.1 install. When looking at the attached devices in my router (Netgear R6220), it's still being listed there with the name of the old windows install. How do I flush the DNS on the router so that the new hostname of the Ubuntu install will be shown and accessible within the network? The router has been rebooted already, as has the PC.

The system connects to the router via ethernet through a TP-Link managed switch.

Ultimately, I'd like to be able to browse to this machine over the network using it's new hostname. When trying to connect using the new hostname, I get an error that the name is not known. I'm hoping the error is because the router has the wrong hostname listed. So I'd like to know if there's some way to flush the DNS on the router, beyond restoring it to factory defaults.

Comment: Have you clicked the "Refresh" button on the "View Devices Currently on the Network" page? Does the router show which machine it is using for DNS (basic home screen -> "Internet"), and, if so, is that machine one you can edit things on?

Comment: The refresh button had no impact, just reloaded the page with the same device names listed for them. Router is using ISP for it's DNS servers.

Comment: The only place my router (not Netgear) has Host Name is in the main setup and is entered manually. Did you check your documentation for that?

Comment: [How does my router identify different devices?](https://superuser.com/a/807603/272824) suggests that the router got the name from the PC. Have you tried searching for the PC's "old" name in the PC's config files?

Comment: A screenshot would help. AFAIK, most home routers do not provide DNS resolution for local host names on the network. You may have thought that due to Windows NetBIOS or some other mechanism that works outside of DNS. What you might be seeing, instead, is the hostname tied to the IP address via DHCP. In this case, the router sees the same MAC (hardware) address and still associates that MAC with the old hostname. So you are looking to clear a device/dhcp entry and it has nothing to do with DNS at all. Quite possibly Linux is not providing updated information when it obtains an IP address.

Comment: @Appleoddity You are right, I was mistaking windows NetBIOS for DNS resolution within the local network. Testing name resolution from the linux machine to another linux machine that has the correct host listed in the router gives name not known error. I'll go ahead and close the question, as the ultimate goal is not possible via this question. Since this new install is going to be a lab, getting a dhcp/dns server that can resolve local hostnames can be the next thing I use it to learn.